# Multiple Items but want one SKU for all Item which fall under same category

Tags: magento-1.9, php, zend-framework, ecommerce-tracking

I am newbie to Magento. I have multiple items (say it1,it2,it3 ... ) from same item category (say itcat1 ) in my store.

**How can I set same stock for all items or some item from same category?**

One solution I have for CakePHP is set one item as "stock count item" (say stockit1 ) do not display it to site. maintain its id in other items as "stock item id". When originally user buy it1's 1 quantity it will decremented from stockit1.

**Is the same can work in Magento? 
If yes then brief me how else explain any other way?**

Answer (score 0):

In Catalog > Manage Products overview, you can select which products you want to update attributes for. Then in the top right of the overview you see "Actions", if you click the dropdown you can select Update Attributes.

[image]

Then on the left you have Inventory where you can set the stock for those items.
Hope this answers your question.

Comment: This is what you explain is for one item having one SKU. I need it1, it2.. fall under same category itcat1 and having one SKU in common. Repeat my solution here, tell me is it feasible or not. One solution I have for CakePHP is set one item as "stock count item" (say stockit1 ) do not display it to site. maintain its id in other items as "stock item id". When originally user buy it1's 1 quantity it will decremented from stockit1.

Comment: I'm pretty sure SKU needs to be unique for each product. You can save the SKU in a non-unique field. Further, if you want to keep stock level for it1 the same but decrement stock on product with stock-item-id it1, you can't do it with Magento admin. Perhaps with some code you can achieve it.