# How much configurations we can do with Magento 1.9 , How it will be differ than cakephp?

Tags: magento-1.9, php-5.4, zend-framework

I am newbie to Magento? I want to know how CakePHP and Magento differs. I have found most of the common folder structure. What is the relation between Zend and Magento? Kindly ignore if question repeats.

Comment: My question is quite simillar to this but generic @ProxiBlue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34072524/add-custom-column-to-magento-report-and-sales-dashboard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They differ in many ways...and they are the same in some ways.

I have never used cakePHP. It is a framework.

So is Zend.

They are both based on the MVC pattern, hence the similarity in their structure (this is an assumption based on your comment regarding the folder structure, as I had never looked at cakePHP)

Zend and cakePHP would be considered the same thing, allowing you to create software. That software can be anything, within limits of the common language, which is of course PHP.

Magento is based on zend. There is your relation.

Magento is also a framework, based on another framework, for one specific purpose: building e-commerce sites.

Hope that clarifies, and obviously anyone please correct me if I got it wrong.

Comment: Thanks! How much configurtions we can do in magento. As I get that when I create first site It will generate 250 tables in database for the same. I don't want to buy any plugins for site as it has only 20 products on satrtup level. I want to put my own created skins and layouts, Want database design changes as I needed. In future want to enhance it with    nosql db. Is all of this possible or not.

Comment: How much configurations we can do in magento? How long is a piece of string? Your question makes no sense, sorry.

Comment: Short one: _Can I change database table structure as I need?_ I want to add few fields/columns as my requirement and want to remove a few.

Comment: Yes you can. Everything is ultimately configurable. Some by default, some by code. Please ask a new question, rather than use the comments for additional questions

Comment: Here is my [new question](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/93994/multiple-items-but-want-one-sku-for-all-item-which-fall-under-same-category)